# CSS Radio button label require circle

Tags: html, css

I have radio button and I am trying to show circle on each lable

```
 <ul>
     <li>
         <input type='radio' value='1' name='radio' id='radio1'/>
         <label for='radio1'>Value 1</label>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

and css for this

```
 ul {
     list-style: none;
 }
 li {
     display: inline-block;
     margin-right: 15px;
 }
 input {
     visibility:hidden;
 }
 label {
     cursor: pointer;
 }
 input:checked + label {
     background: red;
 }
```

I need to show lable of each radio button with circle 
I got this example from [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/petrabarus/pPgS7/)

Comment: Fix your formatting (remove `>` from your code). And describe what is the issue you have.

Comment: Need HTML, *without assuming anything*, it looks like you don't have radio buttons.

Comment: Can't you see that your question doesn't render HTML? In order to make it look proper remove `>` from code block. This is not a quote.

Comment: @dfsq just remove '>'

Comment: @VipinSharma this way? https://jsfiddle.net/ckp2bLbx/

Comment: And now explain better what circle you want? Default radio button or some custom circle?

Comment: @ketan , Value1 require inside the circle only

Comment: @dfsq  custom circle require

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/76ab0rLd/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `border-radius` to make the label a circle.

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
input {
    visibility:hidden;
}
label {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
}
input:checked + label {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type='radio' value='1' name='radio' id='radio1'/>
        <label for='radio1'>Value 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type='radio' value='2' name='radio'  id='radio2'/>
        <label for='radio2'>Value 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type='radio' value='3' name='radio'  id='radio3'/>
        <label for='radio3'>Value 3</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yes , but can we make red background default, its come after check, is it possible?